# Example of an Abstract Factory in .NET

Tags: .net, design-patterns

Are there any good examples of the "Abstract Factory" in the .NET BCL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ADO.Net uses several abstract factory classes.  See [Abstract Factory Design Pattern in ADO.NET 2.0](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/mosessaur/abstractfactoryadonet208102006012837AM/abstractfactoryadonet2.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was hoping to find.

Comment: Remove 's' from end of the link.